# How to avoid orphan line between two figures?

Tags: floats, formatting, line-breaking, line-spacing

I have a annoying line between two fingers, I would  like to avoid this:

[image]

I have tried to change the paragraph location before the second figure, but even though I still have an orphan line at the beginning of the page:

[image]

There are some space at the end of the page after the second figure. I have tried to reduce the size of the figures a bit. I have also tried the `needspace` Package, but it did not help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give us the example file?

Comment: By default figures would not go in that position, they would float to the top of the page above that line of text, as you have not shown any code it is hard to suggest what to change, but not using `h` or `H` is one possibility.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle for the hint. I have removed the [h] option. However, I still have the same problem, but now the profane line "has the higher weight" comes after the two figures. Is there a way to force this line in previous page?

Comment: yes lots of ways, see.. [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110068/how-to-not-have-widows-and-orphans-without-using-raggedbottom) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248417/what-are-the-downsides-of-widowpenalty10000-clubpenalty10000) or generally search the site for "widow" and "orphan"

Comment: That is there are lots of _possible_ ways but whether they work depends on what is on the previous page (and whether you can change that) for example if the page is full of text with no flexible space then the extra line can not be "squeezed in" unless you can change linebreaking (see link above) or change the text or use `\enlargethispage` to get an extra line in that page or ...